# Weighted average with ddply is wrong (R, ddply)

Tags: r

I need to build a weighted average when collapsing rows in R.

Data

```
name = c("car1", "car2", "car2", "car2", "car3", "car1") 
brand = c("b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b1")
production = c(10, 10, 30, 40, 10, 5) 
fuelEconomy= c(1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4)
size = c(10, 50, 30,40,20, 7) 
adf = data.frame(brand, name, production, fuelEconomy, size)
```

Collapse by brand and name

```
adfSum <- ddply(adf, .(brand, name),
                summarise,
                fuelEconomySum = sum(fuelEconomy*production)/sum(production),  
                productionSum = sum(production),  
sizeSum = (sum(size*production)/sum(production)))
```

Results:
The first weighted average (fuelEconomySum) is correct, but the last sizeSum is not correct. The correct values are in brackets.

```
brand name fuelEconomySum production sizeSum
b1 car1 2.000 15 17 (9)
b2 car2 3.875 80 120 (37.5)
b3 car3 2.000 10 20 (20)
```

I am looking for a solution to create multiple weighted averages at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works (using `dplyr` and `magrittr`):

```
name = c("car1", "car2", "car2", "car2", "car3", "car1") 
brand = c("b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b1")
production = c(10, 10, 30, 40, 10, 5) 
fuelEconomy= c(1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4)
size = c(10, 50, 30,40,20, 7) 
adf = data.frame(brand, name, production, fuelEconomy, size)

library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

afdSum <- adf %>% 
  group_by(brand, name) %>% 
  summarise(fuelEconomySum = sum(fuelEconomy*production)/sum(production),
            productionSum = sum(production),
            sizeSum = sum(size*production)/sum(production)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()


> afdSum
    brand name fuelEconomySum productionSum sizeSum
  1    b1 car1          2.000            15     9.0
  2    b2 car2          3.875            80    37.5
  3    b3 car3          2.000            10    20.0
```

Edit: Your solution, incidentally, works fine for me.

```
> devtools::session_info("plyr")
Session info      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
setting  value                       
version  R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
ui       RStudio (0.99.491)          
language en_US                       
collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
tz       <NA>                        
date     2016-09-14                  

Packages     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package * version date       source        
plyr    * 1.8.3   2015-06-12 CRAN (R 3.3.0)
Rcpp      0.12.5  2016-05-14 CRAN (R 3.3.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contributions.  

I found the error. It was in the naming of my variables. I changed the variable name to productionSum to make it clear in this post. But in my script, I just had it named production which is equal to my input. This led to the fact that the last operations already took the sum of production and not the single values.